# Bundling all relevant css files together

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, optimization

I solved issues after bundling my custom stylesheet and bootstrap stylesheet. Then I found the reason in the article [A webpage that uses CSS styles does not render correctly in Internet Explorer](https://support.microsoft.com/en-gb/kb/262161).

Is it a good idea to bundle all the css files into one? (Including all required frameworks css and custom css?)

Answer (score 0):

Usually it's a good idea to bundle as much css and js files as possible, in order to save HTTP Requests. Here's some more info on that topic: [hacks.mozilla.org](https://hacks.mozilla.org/2012/12/fantastic-front-end-performance-part-1-concatenate-compress-cache-a-node-js-holiday-season-part-4/) (see title 'Concatenation').

If you experience problems you should avoid these by not concatenating all of you css into one file but into more files.